# Symptoms of a clogged fuel line (pump runs but engine not starting)?

Tags: fuel-system, golf, fuel-line, fuel-filter

I removed the in-tank fuel pump from my '93 Golf Cabriolet to fix a fuel gauge issue. I noticed a small tear in the mesh filter that goes over the intake nozzle of the pump. I replaced the pump but now the car wont start.

I can hear the pump whirring, so it seems that there is power getting to it but no fuel getting to the engine.

The engine kicks over and almost catches but wont start.

Could this be because I stirred up some crap in the fuel tank which has clogged the fuel lines?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There should be a fuel filter between the fuel pump and distributor. If something has clogged the lines you should see it get caught in the fuel filter, so I'd inspect it to confirm your suspicion. You may also have a fuel accumulator in between the fuel pump and fuel filter where some debris has made its way

Comment: Since this is an in-tank fuel pump, did you ensure the small rubber hose going from the pump to the hard line was securely connected on both ends? Your pump could be pumping, but just recycling the fuel directly back to the tank.

Comment: @Paulster2 yep I did.

Comment: Check the sparkplugs, if they are getting wet, and check the injector rail or fuel line coming to it for fuel. I have ’92 Jetta (2.0L ABA motor) and had to deal with it before, and I cannot remember exactly how to do that, but it wasn’t difficult. Just have plenty of rags around (because fuel supposed to be pressurized in the lines), and no open fire or electrical hazards nearby. Disconnect the battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies all.

I found it was actually the pump. Whilst it was working the bearings were shot so it wasnt working well.

Replaced and all good.